# How can i create a nested dictionary in c#

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, nested

How can i create a nested dictionary which is given below in c#

This is nested json

```
{
   "blue":[
      {
         "s":{
            [
               "store1",
               "store2"
            ],
            "availble"
         }
      },
      {
         "m":{
            [
               "store3",
               "store4"
            ],
            "not availble"
         }
      },
      {
         "l":{
            [
               "store5"
            ],
            "availble"
         }
      }
   ]
},
{
   "back":[
      {
         "xxl":{
            [
               "store2",
               "store4"
            ],
            "not availble"
         }
      },
      {
         "m":{
            [
               "store3",
               "store4"
            ],
            "not availble"
         }
      }

   ]
}
```

I tried with below script but it is not working

```
var variations_hash = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
var stores = new[] {"s","m","xl","xxl","xxxl","v"};
var color_trans = new[] {"blue","black"};
foreach(var store in stores){
if (variations_hash.ContainsKey (color_trans)) {

        List<String> list;
        if (variations_hash.TryGetValue (color_trans, out list)) {
        list.Add (store);
        }

    } else {

       variations_hash[color_trans] = new List<string> { store };
      }
}
```

How could i create nested dictionary in c#?

I want nested dictionary in above format

Comment: have you tried `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>`?

Comment: no if you have solution could you please add code as answer?

Comment: The JSON you posted is not valid.  Check it at [JSONLint.com](http://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: are you sure that json is valid ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy, elegant way to generate the nested dictionary

```
Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, string>> dict = things
    .GroupBy(thing => thing.Foo)
    .ToDictionary(fooGroup => fooGroup.Key,
                  fooGroup => fooGroup.ToDictionary(thing => thing.Bar,
                                                    thing => thing.Baz));
```

Let me know if that helps, it's the most efficient way to generate a nested dictionary in my opinion.